# PL/SQL Calculating Percentage on a Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to PL/SQL and I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to use percentages on triggers. Here is my problem:

I want to create a trigger that whenever the new Price has **decreased**  >20% the trigger will fire, only on a DECREASE. I thought my logic was correct but I cannot get it to work:

Table:

```
Product: pid, price, pname
```

code:

```
set serveroutput on;

show errors;

update product
   set price = 3000
 where pid = 2;

select * from product;

create or replace trigger percentage
after update on product
    for each row when ((((new.price - old.price) / old.price) * 100)>.20)
declare
  x product.pname%type;
  y varchar(100);
begin

y := (((:new.price - :old.price) / :old.price) * 100);


  dbms_output.put_line('The Product: '||:new.pname|| ' price has decreased by: '|| y ||'%');
end;
```

I continue to get errors like this:

```
6/3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the f ollowing: := . ( @ % ;
6/54    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the f ollowing: . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder no t rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like l ike2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
12/4    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting on e of the following: end not pragma final instantiable order o verriding static member constructor map
```

Comment: In the `when` clause of a trigger `:new` and `:old` need to be specified without semicolons, `new` and `old`. Second, `when` condition has unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: changes have been made but it still works when the price is increased.

Comment: If the price increases, your expression `(new.price - old.price) / old.price` will evaluate to a positive number; if it is over 0.2% (note the conversion you're doing) your trigger should fire. If the price decreases, your expression will evaluate to a negative number, which will always be less than `.20`. p.s. why are you multiplying by 100 when you are comparing it with `.20` and not `20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your trigger is written it will only fire if the price **INCREASES** by more than **2/10ths of one percent or more**. Let's run an example:

If `NEW.PRICE` is 101 and `OLD.PRICE` is 100 the calculation in the `WHEN` clause

```
((((new.price - old.price) / old.price) * 100)
```

will compute as

```
((((101 - 100 ) / 100) * 100)
```

and this produces as result of (1 / 100) * 100, which is 1.0. Because 1.0 is greater than 0.20 the trigger will fire.

Clearly this is not what you had in mind.

I think that you want to change your WHEN clause to

```
WHEN ((((OLD.PRICE - NEW.PRICE) / OLD.PRICE) * 100) > 20)
```

Given this, let's reconsider our first example:

```
(((100 - 101) / 100) * 100)
```

produces -1, and the trigger DOESN'T fire, which is correct.

Now, let's consider an example where the trigger should fire. Our old price was 100, our new price is 70, and our calculations become

```
(((100 - 70) / 100) * 100)
```

which produces a result of 30, and so the trigger fires.

Give that a shot.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple representation of the logic would seem to be:

```
new.price < 0.8 * old.price
```

I don't like the idea of expressing a change as a "*decrease* of *more* than ...". The semantics are strange.

"decrease to a value lower than" seems like a better way of expressing it.

Answer (score 1):

the assignment symbol in PL/SQL is ":=" not "=" as you have used in the first line of code after Begin

Comment: made the changes, still has not changed anything

Comment: @user2402107 - "still has not changed **anything**" is **bs** (technical term) - if you did indeed make the changes, the first error (about encountering the symbol `=` on line 6 at position 3) should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each row when ((((new.price - old.price) / old.price) * 100) < -.20)
declare
  y varchar(100);
begin


y:= (((:new.price - :old.price) / :old.price) * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the good advice so far together, you should get something like this:

```
create or replace trigger percentage after update on product for each row
when (new.price < old.price * 0.8)
declare
    l_percent number(6,1) := 100 * (:old.price - :new.price) / nullif(:old.price,0);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Product '||:new.pname||' price has decreased by '|| l_percent ||'%');
end;
```